# Storing the entire workspace output?

Tags: python, pickle

I realise this is a very basic question but as someone used to programming in MATLAB, I’m used to using the save() command which saves all workspace variables/outputs into one single .mat file which can be read in my analysis script.

What’s the closet analog or more effective way to do the same thing in Python?

So I have a solver script which solves an equation and I want to save its output and then load this into a separate analysis script.

The solver outputs [xdata] and [ydata] arrays as well as various variables needed to define precision etc.

Comment: Try looking at [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: Just use jupyter notebooks. Some versions support saving the entire session with variables and everything.